# Teams API: How to get team object immediately after the object is created?

Tags: c#, azure, api, microsoft-teams

I'm using the documentation for [create team in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp). I create an object of team. My problem is that I can't get back the object of my team after the request, in order to take the id.

This is the code I wrote:

```
var team = new Team
            {
    DisplayName = "Name",
    Channels = new TeamChannelsCollectionPage()
    { },
    Members = new TeamMembersCollectionPage()
    {
        new AadUserConversationMember
        {
            Roles = new List<String>()
            {
                "owner"
            },
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "user@odata.bind",
                  $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{ownerId}')" }
            },
        }
    },

    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { templateBind, urlTeamsApiStandard },
    }
};

var createdTeam = await graphClient.Teams //Here I get null
         .Request()
         .AddAsync(team);
```

How to get back the object?

Comment: Those docs say _"If successful, this API returns a 202 Accepted response **that contains a link to the teamsAsyncOperation**."_ and include  a sample response: why are you expecting this code to return the team?

Comment: Does this help? https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/addasync-team-returns-null-even-though-this-is-supposed-to-be/m-p/1938871

Comment: We have raised a bug and the team is looking into it.

Comment: We got the below update from team - The Graph team doesn't return any response as part of this API. The API returns a Location response header that should be used to check the status of the async operation.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from comments section to Answer

We got the below update from team - The Graph team doesn't return any response as part of this API. The API returns a Location response header that should be used to check the status of the async operation